# How to Open the install file same as programs file in ubuntu

Tags: filesystem

I installed PhP on Ubuntu, but I can't open and find the foler `/etc/php/...` to setting.

How do I open the folder `/etc`?

[image: screenshot of Nautilus]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, why is the Windows taskbar shown in your desktop? Are you using either WSL or Virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

- Does the folder exist?
- To go to /etc/ you need to click the search bar or something else (i didn't used ubuntu) and put the directory.
- **Can you desribe the problem with more details?**
- Alternatively, you can open the file in **Terminal**. by default, the terminal is open in the /home/ directory. so you need to do `cd ..` 2 times and then do `cd etc/php` (or `cd etc`)

Answer (score 0):

Use a shortcut key, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
Type `/etc`

[image]